# ListTiles inside ListView won't disappear on scrolling

Tags: flutter

I've got a ListView within a Column. In that Listview I want to place a couple of ListTiles. Unfortunately the tiles behave weird when scrolling. They are shown on top of the other widget placed in the Column

[image]

Is there a way to prevent that behaviour of ListTile?

Here is my code:

```
Column(children: [
    const ChatHeader(),
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            child: ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: myCollection,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  var item = myCollection[index];
                  return Column(children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            decoration: boxDecoration(
                                radius: 20, bgColor: d_colorPrimary)),
                        text("${item.value1}", fontSize: textSizeMedium)
                      ],
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                        dense: true,
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                        tileColor: quiz_light_gray,
                        title: SizedBox(
                            child: text(item.name,
                                fontSize: textSizeMedium,
                                textColor: d_textColorPrimary,
                                isLongText: true,
                                maxLine: 10)))
                  ]);
                }))),
    16.height,
    Container(color: greenColor, child: Text("text input here"))
  ]);
```

Replacing the ListTiles with a Container solves this problem. As far as I can see there is no property to prevent that behaviour. Still want to use ListTiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrapped the SizedBox with the ListView in a Material widget. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perhaps this is because of the usage of `BouncingScrollPhysics()`.
   Try replacing it with `Neverscrollablescrollphysics()` or just wrap the whole `Listview.builder` with an `Expanded` widget. which will let you won't use `shirnkWrap` and `physics` properties.
2. If the `Container` widget fixes the issue then you can try wrapping `Listile()` with another `Sizedbox()` widget.